# How to enable shape keys only for 1 animation?

Tags: armature, export, unity, shape-keys

I have 3 objects: human model, pants and 1 armature for both. Before I started work on pants, I made few animations for body (run, idle). Initial problem was that the pants partially fall into the character during the run animation. I decided to fix that with shape keys. So I made 18  shape keys which made the pants looks correctly in run animation. But when I change animation in armature, shape keys still affect and when I try to export (.fbx for Unity), shape keys change output animations.

So, how can I use key shapes only for 1 animation?

P.S. I know about cloth modifier and weight painting. Both approaches don't work well in my case.

[image]

Comment: The shape key's animation is also an action, so you can turn it on/off in the action editor if you select the mesh object.

Comment: @FFeller, I added my screen with blender. I can't find shape keys in action editor, only in shape key editor, but there shape keys turn on/off for all animations. Can you, plz, explain where should I turn them off?

Comment: Just create a fake user with the shield icon near the "run_shapes" in the Shape key editor, then click on the X to remove the action from the mesh. Later you can reassign it.

Comment: @FFeller, that disables shape keys for all animations, including running, and I want disable them for all animations except running.

Comment: @ФилиппШабатин did you find a solution for this issue?